# Realm: records added, not retrievable in other thread

Tags: android, multithreading, realm

I use Realm.getDefaultInstance() in a worker thread (in a service) and save my records with:

```
Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm) {
               ...
               realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(...
```

When done (this is sync, so it is done right away), I submit an EventBus message to the UI thread that it can start the next task.

The UI thread calls to a different worker thread again which does another Realm.getDefaultInstance() and then a findAll() call. It finds nothing. Why is this? "Some time later" it will find the items fine, but not right away.

The items are in the database already: If I do the findAll() right after saving the items on the first worker thread, it does return the items. If I do it AFTER that again on the second worker thread it finds nothing. Is this some kind of caching?

Comment: Have you read this https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#threading ?

Comment: You could use a listener to update the UI: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#realm-threading-example

Comment: @Tim I read that, it says it should be seemless, but it isn't: "When you want to access the same data from a different thread, you can obtain a new Realm instance (i.e. Realm.getInstance(RealmConfiguration config) or its cousins) and get your objects through a query."

Comment: @geisshirt that might solve it, but the UI thread does not need to do the refresh action on every change. Only when changes were made from the service. I know I could work around this too, but that would make my code hard to read. I want it to work as described above, with an Event that says "synchronization finished", that is cought by any component that wants to do something after that. Right now, these components cannot see the changes made in the database until after a delay.

Comment: The UI thread doesn't know about changes instantaneous, because we might need to re-run any async queries first. Sending an event using EventBus most likely means your event arrives before we get a chance to update. You should use our change listeners instead. They are guaranteed to trigger when it is safe to do so.

Comment: @ChristianMelchior Thanks that at least makes it clear. I guess I'll have to work around it with change listeners. Is there a way to find out in the background thread if the updates on the UI thread were done? So I can delay the SyncFinished eventbus event until it is really finished?

Comment: Not really. But we use the Looper so if you post to `runOnUiThread` that runnable should be executed after we have updated the Realm.

Comment: Okay, that works (already worked, my question is wrong) but the UiThread calls to a different worker thread again: problem persists there. Do you have a short fix for that too, or should I really use listeners to realm on all threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was based on me using a threadpool, on which threads the Realm instance was not updated. A solution for me is to not use the threadpool, so instead of

```
observable
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
```

I now use this everywhere:

```
observable
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
```

And it solves all Realm threading problems. It is a little less efficient probably, but fine for my purpose.